# trying to render pdf in image with but getting the link path wrong

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a pdf file generated in an image folder and display it in my app. I'm using pdf.js and importing `pdfjs-dist` for this purpose. So far I have been able to get the workers working and configured the webpack to load file. But I get an error with file path. No matter how I try to write the file path, I'm getting an error. I'm stuck trying to figure this out. How do I get the pdf to render?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
import pdfPath from '../../../../static/dist/assets/images/sampleStuff.pdf';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '../../../../static/dist/pdf.worker.bundle.js';

class Samplepdf extends Component { 

    state = {
      file: pdfPath
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myCanvas);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    const img = this.refs.image


    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
      ctx.font = "20px Courier"
      ctx.fillText(this.props.text, 210, 75)
    }

   render(){

      var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath);

     return (
        <div> 
         <canvas ref="myCanvas" width={640} height={425} />
         <img ref="image" src= {this.state.file} className="hidden" />
        </div>
      )
   }
 }
```

webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    'main': './client/reactApp/index.js', 
    'pdf.worker': 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/dist"), 
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|pdf)$/, 
        use: [ { loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[name].[ext]', outputPath: './assets/images/' } } ] },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: [
              ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must configure the server running on `localhost:5000` to look in the proper directory. The question is tagged `reactjs`, but react does not serve static files. You have to use some kind of web server to do that.

Comment: That's exactly what it is not doing. ` import pdfPath from '../../../../static/dist/assets/images/sample.pdf';` i have tried to change the file path. But the server is looking for the files in `localhost:5000/assets/images/samplestuff.pdf`

Comment: In your code you are importing a file called `sample.pdf`, but the error message you have included, there's a file called `sampleStuff.pdf`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Despite giving the right file name, get the same error.